# How to restrict access using a button in ASP MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to restrict the access only for the registered users (Members) by the click of a button.

I tried using **[Authoriz]** and **[NoAction]** above my methode in the controller but it didn't work.

This is the code HTML of my button :

```
<p><a href="/Voitures/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car &raquo;</a></p>
```

Comment: "didn't work" *how*?  What specifically did you try and how specifically did it fail?  There are *many* examples and tutorials of how to implement authentication and authorization in ASP.NET MVC.  Stack Overflow doesn't seek to replace those examples and tutorials.  Start with those.

Comment: I tried and I read it many tutos but I didn't successed, I am just want to know if it possible with this html Code or I have to use another way

Comment: Well, the code you're showing is nothing more than an HTML element (containing another HTML element).  So, no, server-side authentication and authorization is *not* possible with *only* this HTML code.  You should really start with those tutorials.  Authorization has nothing to do with the single line of HTML code you're showing.  Go back and try again, and in any given tutorial when you encounter a specific problem with something they're showing you then we can perhaps help with that.

Comment: ok thank you, I will try again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are asking how to restrict access to the onclick action ONLY to registered/logged in users. Here's how you could simply show the link/button only if the User is logged in (using Razor):

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p><a href="/Voitures/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car &raquo;</a></p>
}
```

This could easily be changed to prevent the click action, etc.

EDIT: So to make it so that the link shows, but doesn't go anywhere, you could change it like so:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p><a href="/Voitures/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car &raquo;</a></p>
}
else
{
    <p><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car &raquo;</a></p>
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I try your suggestion, the hole button is disappeared.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show you how to show the link/button, but disable it if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: thanks Scott but I want that the button stays and redirect the user to login page

Comment: That should be as simple as decorating your target Action with [Authorize].

Answer (score 0):

What i have understand from your question that you want to disable a button for a user if he is not logged in.To achieve this you can made a check that if user is not logged in, simply remove the link after that unregistered users will not be able to access the page.

**I will suggest you to redirect the user to login page if he is not currently logged in/registered rather than making button disabled for the anonymous user.**

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated){
   <p><a href="/Voitures/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car&raquo;</a></p>
}
else{
     <p><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sell your Car&raquo;</a></p>
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering me but I want to redirect user to ligin page when he is not yet logged and not disabling the button but thanks anyway